# Design View in Access not bringing up an append query?

Tags: ms-access

I am updating a MS Access away from access. There are some Append Queries that the design view will not come up at all. I read somewhere that if the append is extra old you just need to save the DB as an older version. However, that also fails to do anything.

I am using O365 Access with a 2007-2016 file format DB. It has been upgraded multiple times over the years I would assume it might've started as a 2000 DB.

What can I do to see the design of the append?

Comment: Are you able to view the SQL code for the Append queries? If so, does the target table exist and is accessible from the database?

Comment: I am not able to view anything about the append. It works correctly, but invisibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the Visual Basic IDE (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>), and then open the Immediate Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>), you should then be able to enter the following expression on a new line in the Immediate Window (changing `Query1` to the name of your query) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to view the SQL associated with the query:

```
?CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Query1").SQL
```

You could then inspect the tables/queries referenced in the SQL and see if anything is amiss, or copy the SQL to a new query to see if it exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: You are amazing! This is exactly what I needed Thanks!